# Plupload: updating queue (order) while uploading?

Tags: javascript, file-upload, plupload

While plupload is streaming a set of files to the target server, is it possible to update the queue of plupload without cancelling the current upload progress?

For example, I would like the user to have the following options while currently uploading:

- remove the currently uploading file (thus the first one in the queue)
- add a new file to the queue (at the bottom)
- change the priority of a certain file (thus place it higher or lower in the queue)

  - if the priority is changed to the first item in the queue, the currently send item should be paused and resumed when the new first item has finished uploading

Would this require a modification of plupload or does the current API support this functionality?